# How to create a multi-apps project in Ionic 4?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I try to create a simple **multi-apps project** in Ionic 4, following the ionic documentation, but it doesn't work.

https://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/configuration#multi-app-projects

My config :

- Ionic : v4.12.0
- Angular CLI : 7.3.8
- Node : 10.15.1
- npm : 6.9.0
- Windows 10

What I have done :
I have created a directory “monorepo”.
In this folder, I created a file ionic.config.json and pasted in it the code below:

```
{
  "projects": {}
}
```

In monorepo, I create a second directory : apps.
In this directory (with the command prompt), I write the command :
ionic start "app1" --no-deps

monorepo/ionic.config.json is correctly populated with the data:

```
{
  "projects": {
    "app1": {
      "name": "app1",
      "integrations": {},
      "type": "angular",
      "root": "apps\\app1"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I try to serve the server, it won't work.

`ionic serve --project app1` return me this error message :

```
> ng run app1:serve --host=0.0.0.0 --port=8100
[ng] Project 'app1' could not be found in workspace.
[ng] Error: Project 'app1' could not be found in workspace.
[ng]     at Workspace.getProject (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\core\src\workspace\workspace.js:93:19)
[ng]     at Architect.getBuilderConfiguration (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\node_modules\@angular-devkit\architect\src\architect-legacy.js:117:41)
[ng]     at RunCommand.runSingleTarget (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:160:45)
[ng]     at RunCommand.runArchitectTarget (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:201:35)
[ng]     at RunCommand.run (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\commands\run-impl.js:14:25)
[ng]     at RunCommand.validateAndRun (C:\Users\name\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\command.js:124:31)
[ng]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
[ng]     at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:11)
[ng]     at startup (internal/bootstrap/node.js:283:19)
[ng]     at bootstrapNodeJSCore (internal/bootstrap/node.js:743:3)

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

When I go under the file associated with the error (workspace.js:93:19), and I do console.log, I obtain this info:

```js
getProject(projectName) {
     this._assertLoaded();

     console.log("this.projectName : " + projectName); // this.projectName : app1
     console.log("\n\nthis._workspace.projects : \n");
     console.log(this._workspace.projects); // this._workspace.projects : app and app-e2e

     const workspaceProject = this._workspace.projects[projectName];
```

(Values displayed are in comments).

The projectName variable seems ok. But the available project in `this._workspace.projects` are app and app-e2e which seem weird.

What is my problem ?
What did I miss ?

Comment: I have find a solution.
Go to your `angular.json` file (for both project). Duplicate the app under `projects`in the hierarchy. And rename one, `app1` (with app1 being the name of the project). Now, you can have multiple angular app within one project structure.
But I can't find a way to reuse components or pages from one app in another.

Comment: off topic-ish, how did you add a lib project? I can't find it in the current docs. Is just another ionic app?

Comment: @Zahema Not really, my lib isn't referenced in the ionic.config.json, but is present in the angular.json as a project.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I managed to compile by replacing in the `angular.json` every `app` keyword by the name of my ionic project (here, `app1`).

```json
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular-devkit/core/src/workspace/workspace-schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "defaultProject": "app1",                      <-- HERE
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "app1": {                                    <-- HERE
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app1",                          <-- NOT MANDATORY
      "schematics": {},
      "architect": {
        "build": { ... },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "app1:build"        <-- HERE
          },
   ...
}
```

I suppose that instead of putting several angular apps within one project structure you should rewrite each ionic project's `angular.json`